# JVM: how are exit codes of the java executable defined?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm looking for a definition of possible exit codes of the `java` executable:

**(How) can I tell whether the exit code is of the executed Java process or of the VM itself?**

Example: On Windows, `java -badoption` returns `1`; `java Main` with `Main` being a valid class may return `1` as well.

Are there any VM options I could use to make exit codes more meaningful? E.g. to distinguish between both types of exit codes?

**If I know that the exit code is not from my Java process (which only returns `0`), what do non-zero exit codes mean?**

On Windows, I'm frequently seeing `-1` and `1`. As these are reported through an automated bug-reporting facility, I can't see any error messages. I only have the exit code and need to interpret it.

**Are the exit codes platform-dependent?**

Comment: `System.exit()` has an int argument. As long you have access to the sources, you can define your exit code, ex `System.exit(1040)`.

Comment: @PeterMmm , I don't think this his question. He asked for the action of this function on the return of the VM command.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671234/is-there-a-complete-list-of-jvm-exit-codes

Answer (score 6):

### Meaning of Exit Codes (in general)

#### ISO/IEC 9899 (Programming Languages: C), ISO/IEC 9945 (IEEE 1003, POSIX)

There is nothing which is specifically defined for Java / JVM. The meaning of these exit codes is defined by ISO/IEC 9899 (Programming Languages: C, for example 7.20.4.3 The `exit` function of [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)), ISO/IEC 9945 (IEEE 1003, POSIX) and similar specifications, and it's always like this:

- 0 means success
- Any other value means failure

This is used by shell environments (`sh`, `bash`, `cmd.exe`, `make` etc. etc.) to determine whether a program exited successfully (0) or there was an error (not 0).

It is strongly recommended to use only 0 for success. Programs which use values other than 0 for success cause headache to the authors of shell scripts, Makefiles and alike.

It's up to the individual program to define additional semantics of different failure values. However, I think `-1` is not such a good idea. The best thing would be to use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, however, these definitions from `<stdlib.h>` have no corresponding counterparts in Java. ISO/IEC 9899:2011 does not describe how `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` should be defined. However, it defines 0 as having the same semantics as `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and I do not know of any system which does something else than the following, which therefore is the best thing a Java programmer can assume:

```
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1
```

So, I'd use 0 for success, 1 for failure, and values distinct from 1 if it is important to differentiate between different types of failure. A good example is the `grep` command. From its man page (GNU grep):

> EXIT STATUS
>       The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found. If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX error handling code should check for '2' or greater.)

I'd not use -1 because it sets all bits, and depending on the environment, -1 might actually accidentally generate additonal bogus information, like claiming that signals were raised and alike. Actually, to be portable, the exit code should be within the range `[0..127]`, unless you really really really know what you're doing.
For example, on most POSIX systems, the exit code will be truncated to 8 bits, and the semantics of an exit code above 127 is that the exit was caused by a signal.

#### BSD

BSD has tried to supply a few more exit codes, which are available in `/usr/include/sysexits.h` ([man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits)). They are like this:

- 64: command line usage error
- 65: data format error
- 66: cannot open input
- 67: addressee unknown
- 68: host name unknown
- 69: service unavailable
- 70: internal software error
- 71: system error (i.e. can't fork)
- 72: critical OS file missing
- 73: can't create (user) output file
- 74: input/output error
- 75: temp failure; user is invited to retry
- 76: remote error in protocol
- 77: permission denied
- 78: configuration error

In the absence of any other meaningful standard, I think the best thing we can do is use them.

### Interpretation of JVM-generated exit values

#### JVM on POSIX

On UNIX, you can obtain the signal by masking out the lower 7 bits (subtract 128) from the exit value, which in most shells can be queried using `$?`.

- `SIGTERM` -> VM: `143` `SIGTERM`
- `SIGSEGV` -> VM: `134` `SIGABRT` (because the VM handles SIGSEGV to write the hs_err file and then calls `abort()`).

Comparison to "normal" programs:

- `SIGSEGV` -> prog: `139` `SIGSEGV`

This behavior is not explicitly specified for the JVM, it is just the normal expected behavior of programs in a POSIX environment. Even the `SIGABRT` instead of `SIGSEGV` is more or less expected, given that the JVM wants to handle `SIGSEGV` on its own, writing a more specific crash dump than a normal core file.

#### JVM on Windows

TODO

Comment: Thanks, though that sounds like a quite general answer; as @maerics has pointed out, there is some meaning to exit codes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671234) and I'm wondering whether there is more about that. As I've pointed out, I'm seeing `-1` as well as `1` on Windows and I don't think that this is random; i.e. there are specific conditions where the JVM exits with `-1` and other conditions where the JVM exits with `1`. My question is exactly about these conditions.