# AWS-EMR error exit code 143

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I'm running an analysis on AWS EMR, and I am getting an unexpected SIGTERM error.

**Some background:**

I'm running a script that reads in many csv files I have stored on S3, and then performs an analysis. My script is schematically:

analysis_script.py

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
import boto3

#Spark context
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.csv("s3n://csv_files/*", header = True)

def analysis(df):
    #do bunch of stuff. Create output dataframe
    return df_output

df_output = analysis(df)
```

I launch the cluster using:

```
aws emr create-cluster 
--release-label emr-5.5.0 
--name "Analysis" 
--applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Spark  Name=Ganglia  
--ec2-attributes KeyName=EMRB,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole 
--service-role EMR_DefaultRole 
--instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=r3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=4,InstanceType=r3.xlarge 
--region us-west-2 
--log-uri s3://emr-logs/ 
--bootstrap-actions Name="Install Python Packages",Path="s3://emr-bootstraps/install_python_packages_custom.bash",Args=["numpy pandas boto3 tqdm"] 
--auto-terminate
```

I can see from logs that the reading in of the csv files goes fine. But then it finishes with errors. The following lines are in the stderr file:

```
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 143
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 143, (reason: User application exited with status 143)
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.31.36.42:36169
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 908.0 in stage 1494.0 (TID 88112, ip-172-31-35-59.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 27, partition 908, RACK_LOCAL, 7278 bytes)
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 874.0 in stage 1494.0 (TID 88078) in 16482 ms on ip-172-31-35-59.us-west-2.compute.internal (executor 27) (879/4805)
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2328_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-36-42.us-west-2.compute.internal:34133 (size: 28.8 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerBlockUpdated(BlockUpdatedInfo(BlockManagerId(20, ip-172-31-36-42.us-west-2.compute.internal, 34133, None),broadcast_2328_piece0,StorageLevel(memory, 1 replicas),29537,0))
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2328_piece0 in memory on ip-172-31-47-55.us-west-2.compute.internal:45758 (size: 28.8 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerBlockUpdated(BlockUpdatedInfo(BlockManagerId(16, ip-172-31-47-55.us-west-2.compute.internal, 45758, None),broadcast_2328_piece0,StorageLevel(memory, 1 replicas),29537,0))
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1494 failed: toPandas at analysis_script.py:267, took 479.895614 s
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 1494 (toPandas at analysis_script.py:267) failed in 478.993 s due to Stage cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerSQLExecutionEnd(0,1531742546839)
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@28e5b10c)
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 1495 (toPandas at analysis_script.py:267) failed in 479.270 s due to Stage cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@6b68c419)
18/07/16 12:02:26 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerJobEnd(1494,1531742546841,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1494 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down))
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices(serviceOption=None, services=List(),started=false)
18/07/16 12:02:26 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
```

I can't find much useful information about exit code 143. Does anybody know why this error is occurring? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a newer version EMR or looking at the Spark UI?... Please show the "do bunch of stuff" code because I'm guessing that calling `toPandas` killed your executor because it ran out of memory after almost 500 seconds

Comment: Yes essentially I'm running aggregation functions on all the columns of this big Spark dataframe, which shrinks the size, and then I call toPandas

Comment: Shrinks it to what size, though? Is that size larger than the executor memory?

Comment: I'm confused as to why 'toPandas' would be the issue? The code is something like 'df.agg.("sum").toPandas()'. Wouldn't it be the agg function that is causing issues and not the toPandas?

Comment: Because toPandas is downloading every RDD partition into a single machine. The agg function itself is a lazy operation

Comment: Ok yes I've confirmed that when the Spark dataframe is too large, the code hangs on the `toPandas` call. Any ideas on how fix / avoid this?

Comment: I don't know EMR, but I would recommend increasing the executor memory from the default values

Answer (score 1):

Spark passes through exit codes when they're over 128, which is often the case with JVM errors.  In the case of exit code 143, it signifies that the JVM received a `SIGTERM` - essentially a unix kill signal ([see this post for more exit codes and an explanation](http://journal.thobe.org/2013/02/jvms-and-kill-signals.html)).  Other details about Spark exit codes [can be found in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428145/do-exit-codes-and-exit-statuses-mean-anything-in-spark).

Since you didn't terminate this yourself, I'd start by suspecting something else externally did.  Given that precisely 8 minutes elapse between job start and a `SIGTERM` being issued, it seems much more likely that EMR itself may be enforcing a maximum job run time/cluster age.  Try checking through your EMR settings to see if there is any such timeout set - there was one in my case (on AWS Glue, but the same concept).