# What does -1000 mean in spark exit status

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm doing something with `Spark-SQL` and got error below:

> YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to
>   remove executor 1 for reason Container marked as failed:
>   container_1568946404896_0002_02_000002 on host: worker1. Exit status:
>   -1000. Diagnostics: [2019-09-20 10:43:11.474]Task java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService$QueueingFuture@76430b7c
>   rejected from
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.concurrent.HadoopThreadPoolExecutor@16970b[Terminated,
>   pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks =
>   1]

I'm trying to figure it out by checking the meaning of `Exit status: 1000`, however, no valuable info returned by googling.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45524760/3378204), the `-1000` is not even mentioned.

Any comment is welcomed, thanks.

Comment: It looks like a yarn exception, not spark. Here is a list which includes -1000, but I don't think it will help much: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_sg_yarn_container_exec_errors.html

Comment: @Shaido It makes sense that the error is thrown from Yarn side. Thanks. I will try to check yarn log to figure out what happened.