# How to handle the output of .jar file in a batch file if the jar file throws an exception?

Tags: java, batch-file

I have created a JAR file named "FileProcessor.jar" which consist of:

```
public class FileProcessor{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            // logic
        }catch(Exception ex){
        // catch logic
        }
    }
}
```

I need to run different logic according to the output of the jar file. If an exception arises I need to call a different jar file.

Comment: Catch the exception and set an exit code with System.exit, then check for this in the batch with `if errorlevel`

Comment: @Marged With a little more detail that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest shape this could be done like this:

```
try{
  // logic
}
catch(Exception ex){
  System.exit( 1 );
}
System.exit( 0 );
```

In the batch do:

```
@echo off
java -jar ...
if errorlevel 1 goto runother
if errorlevel 0 goto allok
...
```

Please remember that `if errorlevel` has an implicit "greater than or equal". If the JVM crashes it sets an exit code on its own, you can read more about it here: [Is there a complete List of JVM exit codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671234/is-there-a-complete-list-of-jvm-exit-codes)