# Knime: Invoking Knime workflow from Java application

Tags: java, data-mining, knime

I have tried to invoke `knime` workflow in batchmode

```
String btchtrendcheck ="E:\\KNIME\\knime.exe -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -consoleLog -reset -workflowFile=\"C:\\Users\\Jana\\Desktop\\KNIMETrend.zip\""

String trendtest = "E:\\KNIME\\knime.exe -application org.knime.product.KNIME_APPLICATION";
```

However I get an error: `java was started but returned exit code=3` (attached the error) and even on clicking OK , the workflow was not executed.
[image: Knime Error]

There is no error in the workflow.

**Questions :**
**1.** *What does the exit code=3 mean?*
**2.** *Is there any issue with compatibility with knime?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454114/java-exit-codes-and-meanings

Comment: Thanks for that info! I could not find the cause for exit code 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the command without options, e.g.
    `eclipsec.exe -consoleLog -noexit -nosplash -launcher.suppressErrors -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION`

then you will see a list of the available options and the java return codes.  A return code 3 indicates `when an error occurs during loading a workflow`, and 4 indicates `if an error during execution occurred`.

Most likely, you need to open the workflow in the KNIME desktop, check for errors, reset the workflow and save it again, as an error during loading (e.g partially executed loops to pick a common one) could cause this.  Then try re-loading the workflow in the KNIME desktop and check no errors during load are recorded during the console.
Also, adding the option `--launcher.suppressErrors` can sometimes avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the -consoleLog option, then a second window appears with more verbose output explaining the error. 
In case of error code 3 this might be because the workflow is open in a GUI environment (and therefore locked).
In case of error code 4 it might be because a class could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with the -consoleLog -noexit -nosplash  options?

According to this:
https://tech.knime.org/faq#q12

it looks like they're necessary.

Comment: Did you try unzipping the file and executing it with -workflowDir ?

Comment: I just tried it and also get exit.cod=4 because I had saved the workflow in a state where some of the node were restored partially executed. Is your workflow reset (enough) to just execute it when loading?

Comment: What text do you get in the cmd console when you execute KNIME headless?

Comment: Thank you Sampson. I have tried to invoke in zip as well as a folder using workflowdir. Reset is used in command line to reset the workflow. Is that not enough ? I will reset the workflow n check.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run Knime process as a loop ? Because Knime cannot run the same workflow at the same time.
If yes, you have to kill preceding workflow process.